# read only and write only buffers

Tags: opencl

I have an opencl buffer that is used by kernel A as read only, and kernel B 
as read_write.  SO, the buffer is created read_write.

In kernel A, is there a way of indicating that the buffer is read only for this
kernel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can indicate it by setting the pointer as constant:

```
__kernel void mykernel (__global const int * a, ...)
```

Or even by setting the memory as constant memory (if it fits in the constant space):

```
 __kernel void mykernel (__constant int * a, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there not an open cl specific flag for this?

Comment: There is https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/accessQualifiers.html but only for images.